# 3D NumPy array which contains the neighbors of every value in a 2D NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time-complexity, convolution

I want to build a NumPy array of shape `(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3)` where `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` correspond to the shape of an image stored inside a standard NumPy array, in which every `(i, j)` position has the inmediate neighbors (in a certain direction) of that position. For example, if `A = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]` and I want the neighbors of `(1, 2)` positioned to the north, I would get as a result `[1, 2, 3]`. So, my result matrix should have `[1, 2, 3] = A[1:4]` at its respective `(1, 2)`.

For now, I have tried a simple approach in which I do not use such a matrix, instead I iterate over all values in my array and slice it accordingly to get the desired neighbors. Nonetheless, if I could compute that matrix beforehand, the algorithm I use afterwards could be vectorized (I don't include this part in the question because it's not relevant to my problem), which is almost always faster at the expense of more memory usage.

```
    scales = 3
    padded_img = np.pad(img, scales, mode='constant')
    feature_vectors = np.zeros((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 4*scales))
    z = 0
    for i in range(scales, padded_img.shape[0] - scales):
        for j in range(scales, padded_img.shape[1] - scales):
            for scale in range(1, scales + 1):
                N = padded_img[i - scale, j - scale: j + scale + 1]
                E = padded_img[i - scale: i + scale + 1, j + scale]
                S = padded_img[i + scale, j - scale: j + scale + 1]
                W = padded_img[i - scale: i + scale + 1, j - scale]

                neighbors = np.vstack((N, E, S, W))
                avgs = np.mean(neighbors, axis=1)
                           
                feature_vectors[z, 4*(scale-1):4*scale] = avgs.flatten()
            z += 1
```

`img` is my original NumPy array; I pad it to avoid problems in the corners. On the other hand, I use `scales` because I basically need not only the inmediate neighbors, but those distanced 1 to `scales` from a certain position. Since I am also interested in all possible directions, I use `N, E, S, W` as my vectors of neighbors inside the loop. Above all, the idea is to reduce this algorithm's time complexity. Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**: After getting those 4 vectors every iteration, I compute their average, flatten them and append them to a feature vector, whose rows contain this information of all directions on all 4 scales.

Comment: A lot of reducing the complexity will depend on what you are doing with `N, E, S, W` vectors afterwards.  Looks like the start of a brute force convolution algorithm, but without knowing the follow-on operations we can't suggest a convolution kernel to use with [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) to replace it.

Comment: Or rather [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve) or some homebrewed `as_strided` solution if you can only use `numpy`

Comment: I edited my answer to include what I do afterwards with those vectors. Is there a kernel that does this?

Comment: . . . ugh.  Yeah, that can be convolved but . . . it may take a bit of tinkering.  Getting pulled off to work, hopefully question's in a state that someone else can help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this here so that people who may come across this question can have the full picture. I encountered this problem when I was creating a Python implementation for the extraction of multi-scale features explained in the paper ***Segmentation of structural features in cheese micrographs using pixel statistics*** by G. Impoco, L. Tuminello, N. Fucà, M. Caccamo and G. Licitra. You can check it out in [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168169911002298).

I first created a naïve approach consisting of a not-so-elegant triple for-loop that went like this (posted in my original question):

```
import numpy as np

padded_img = np.pad(img, scales, mode="constant")
for i in range(scales, padded_img.shape[0] - scales):
    for j in range(scales, padded_img.shape[1] - scales):
        for scale in range(1, scales + 1):
            N = padded_img[i - scale, j - scale : j + scale + 1]
            E = padded_img[i - scale : i + scale + 1, j + scale]
            S = padded_img[i + scale, j - scale : j + scale + 1]
            W = padded_img[i - scale : i + scale + 1, j - scale]
```

This approach obtained the desired neighborhood information by using a variable `scale` that would iterate over the predefined window radius. This variable allowed me to access the neighboring pixels of `(i, j)`. Nevertheless, as @Daniel F pointed out, this can be convolved and made simpler like so:

```
import scipy.ndimage

directions = 4
for scale in range(1, scales + 1):
    filter_size = 2 * (scale - 1) + 3
    orig = np.zeros((filter_size, filter_size), dtype=np.float64)
    orig[:, 0] = 1 / filter_size
    for c in range(directions):
        # c = 0 -> North; c = 1 -> East; c = 2 -> South; c = 3 -> West
        correlation_filter = np.rot90(orig, 3 - c, (0, 1))
        convolution_filter = np.flip(correlation_filter)

        directions_img = scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, convolution_filter, cval=0.0, mode="constant")
```

So, instead of iterating over every pixel and computing what I wanted that many times, this iterates over the wanted `directions` (`N`, `E`, `W` and `S` in my naïve approach) and computes everything I need for every single pixel, without the need of actually iterating over every single one of them.

Naturally, the difference in performance is mind-blowing. I tested out both versions with `timeit` module (`mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each`) and got the following benchmark with an image of shape `(630, 630)` and `scales=1`:

```
Naïve approach: 46.4 ± 1.65 s per loop 
Convolution approach: 204 ± 11.7 ms per loop
```

#### Comparison over different image sizes with `scales=1`

[image: Comparison between naive approach and convolution approach]

#### Convolution approach over different image sizes with `scales=3`

[image: Convolution approach benchmark]

#### Code

You can check out my code for both versions in [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/CamiloMartinezM/589426b6861398ade582afcde60a6daf). Keep in mind that this code was specifically written for gray images.

Comment: If you're expanding on my answer it's usually better to just edit your improvements into it.  I'm  happy to accept edits like this.  Sorry I didn't manage to get back to you on the RGB issue, my SO time has been very limited the last few months.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed rude. I actually didn't know if you were still active or if someone would ever accept the edit, so I figured I would just post another answer and paint the whole picture there. Plus, since my case was actually about gray images and your answer covered RGB images, editing that wouldn't have provided more, but taken some of it. You pointed me in the right direction and I found the `np.rot90` bit neat. I didn't even know that function existed.

Comment: Nah, it's fine, just for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't run (there's problems with `pad` padding the RGB dimension and the shape of `avgs` not allowing assignment into `feature_vectors`), so I can't tell if this exactly what you want, but this should get you started:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

scales = 3

img = np.random.rand(256, 256, 3)

feature_vectors = np.zeros((scales, 4) + img.shape[:-1])

for n in range(scales):
    dim = 2 * n + 3
    orig = np.zeros((dim, dim, 3), dtype = float)
    orig[:, 0, :] = 1 / (dim * 3)
    kernel = np.array([np.rot90(orig, i, (0, 1)) for i in range(4)])
    feature_vectors[n] = convolve( img[None, ...], 
                                   kernel,
                                   mode = 'constant')[..., 1]
    
feature_vectors = feature_vectors.transpose(2, 3, 1, 0).reshape(-1, scales * 4)

feature_vectors.shape
Out[]: (65536, 12)
```

Comment: Thank you. And you're right, my code would not work with RGB images; I forgot to mention that I'm working with gray images, so I only have one channel and not three. On the other hand, could you explain what happens inside the for loop?